# Pointer aritmetic, adding char pointer to an uint

Tags: pointers

I have the following code:

```
unsigned int a = 1;
unsigned int b = 2;
char *c = "Something";

unsigned int d = *(unsigned int *)(c + a + b);
```

And I don't know exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an integer to a pointer offsets the pointer by the size of the structure it is pointing to.

For example, let us take a char* pointer, and assume that in my machine char is 8 bits.

```
char* a="HELLO!!!"
```

a pointer to 'H', now when you add '3' to it, it now points to 'L'.

Now in the second step you cast this to an 'unsigned int *'. Assuming 'unsigned int' on my system is 32 bits, what this does is, the 'unsigned int *' is pointing to something that is 32 bits long. so when you do this,

```
char* a="HELLO!!!";
a+=3; //a now points to 'L'
unsigned int* ptr=(unsigned int*)(a); // ptr now points to an integer which 
//is 32 bits wide. 
unsigned d=*ptr;
```

Now what the last step does is assign the ASCII value of 'LLO!' (32 bits) stored to d.

Answer (score 0):

In C, `foo[i]` means the same as `*(foo+i)`. So in your example, `*(c + a + b)` means `c[a+b]`, or `c[3]`, which is the letter 'e'.

Because you cast to a pointer to unsigned int, you don't get the letter 'e'. The machine will read as many chars as will fit into an unsigned int, and put them together in whatever endianness your machine is using, to get an unsigned int value.

In other words, what you get is not defined, but would be predictable if you know the characteristics of the machine the code is running on.